# Is there a way to union a multiple dataset on quicksight?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Im trying to create a cohort on quicksight but there are many involved tables. I tried to use custom query but its getting an error as you can see on the screenshot. I came up with an idea to create a multiple datasets on every table i need but creating an union on multiple dataset doesn't seem possible . Is there a way to execute multiple union on one dataset or is there a way to create a complex query using the custom query? TIA.[image: this is the error i get when i put my complex query on custom query on quicksight]

Answer (score 0):

You provide very limited details to your solution above, without those I suspect anyone is going to struggle to help you.  Ie what database are you attempting to query - Athena/RDS etc.  I'd suggest the starting place to start will be permissions (IAMS), then checking logs etc.